# Snowflake Calling APIs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

With external functions we can now call API via a gateway.

However, we have snowflake on our AWS estate and currently use azure API Gateway (we are multi cloud). Is this scenario supported? If so is it possible to route traffic privately? We're on aws private-link and vpn to both aws and azure.

Are there any other ways to call internally hosted APIs from snowflake instance, or are external functions via the gateway the best/only way currently.

Comment: The Snowflake documentation says that the azure API Gateway is supported. Unfortunately, I've no idea if it works with private link, etc. That's probably a level of complexity that needs a discussion with your Snowflake account manager, especially as this relatively new functionality so there wont be that much experience of it out there.

Comment: It's not overly clear. It looks like it uses the msi under the hood so should be ok. It just seems to be a routing issue which is public only. I've reached out to sf for more info. many thanks.